# Return objects array from React.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think my title is not very clear, but I don't know how to entitle this question, so I gladly accept any improvements :)

So, I am trying to create a ReactJS component, `UIBlogLoader` which would return one or more `UIBlogStoryCard` components. I will use a simplified example for this question. Here is my code:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var objects = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      objects.push( <div>Component with number {i}</div> );
    }
    return objects;
  }
});
```

This will give me an error saying that I return `undefined` from `render`.

I found a way to make this work, but I don't want to create the `UIBlogStoryCard`s (in the simplified example, the `div`s) inside one other `<div />`. [Here (on Codepen)](http://codepen.io/victorbarbu/pen/MaObdN/) is the working code:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var objects = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      objects.push( <div>Component with number {i}</div> );
    }
    return <div> {objects} </div>;
  }
});
React.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById("mountNode");
);
```

But this will leave me with something like this:

```
<div id="mountNode">
  <div data-reactid=".0">
    <span data-reactid=".0.0"> </span>
    <div data-reactid=".0.1:0">
      <span data-reactid=".0.1:0.0">Component </span>
      <span data-reactid=".0.1:0.1">0</span>
    </div>
    <div data-reactid=".0.1:1">
      <span data-reactid=".0.1:1.0">Component </span>
      <span data-reactid=".0.1:1.1">1</span>
    </div>

    <!-- and so on -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the inner `div`s to be direct children of `div#mountNode`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: React does not allow that. You need a mounting DOM node (in your case `div#mountNode`). And any render can only return ONE component. That's why you inevitable end up with a (redundant) wrapper inside your mountNode.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html